# VBA Send debugging info to myself

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an excel addin but I want to find a way to get the debugging information to myself. My users are very far and run on different OS's and Office versions. I have tried emailing but the outlook security warnings are giving me a hard time and the CDO mail object needs smtp details which will be different for all my users. Is there something like general smtp settings that will always work ? Any other suggestion are welcome.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by hard time? In VBA you should be able to send an e-mail rather easily and in that e-mail put the details you need.

Comment: can't you use **ThisWorkbook.SendMail Recipients:=name, SUbject:="Debug info"** ?

Comment: instead of your app trying to email why not create a dump file say in a notepad and then request the user to copy paste from that notepad into an email of their choice? That's what I did for one of my commercial add-ins? Also I use MZ Tools to number my code lines and then used `ERL` which dumped the procedure name and the line number into the text file. It has really been successful. Let me know if you want an example?

Comment: Lift - I dont want the user to click on security warnings when sending an email in outlook and i doubt they will know their smtp details for the cdo method.

Comment: Philip - I am testing that now.

Comment: Siddhart Rout - The Mz tools looks very interesting - it would be super if you can direct me to an example. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Philip - just tested that now on office 2010. I still get the security warning that says "The application is trying to send and email message"

Comment: well, that Outlook Security message came about after the horrendous Melissa and ILOVEYOU virus's that were extremely embarrassing to Microsoft (what, you didn't know about that feature of VB Script and known file types?, said MS!). This means that using VBA there **is no easy way to send an email without the dialog**. Of course, you could try the [API methods in MAPI32.DLL](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/21267-sending-email-using-excel-visual-basic-applications-code.html#post98793)

Answer (score 0):

there is code and documentation available on the web for sending mail using SMTP from Excel in VBA:

[Chip Pearson: Sending Email with VBA and Collaboration Data Objects](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Email.aspx)

The code requires a reference to **Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library**
. The typical file location of this file is **C:\Windows\system32\cdosys.dll**. The GUID of this component is {CD000000-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D}, with Major = 1 and Minor = 0.

```
' COPIED FROM Chip Pearson Website: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Email.aspx
'
Function SendEMail(Subject As String, _
        FromAddress As String, _
        ToAddress As String, _
        MailBody As String, _
        SMTP_Server As String, _
        BodyFileName As String, _
        Optional Attachments As Variant = Empty) As Boolean
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' SendEmail Function
' By Chip Pearson, chip@cpearson.com www.cpearson.com 28-June-2012
'
' This function sends an email to the specified user.
' Parameters:
'   Subject:        The subject of the email.
'   FromAddress:    The sender's email address
'   ToAddress:      The recipient's email address or addresses.
'   MailBody:       The body of the email.
'   SMTP_Server:    The SMTP-Server name for outgoing mail.
'   BodyFileName:   A text file containing the body of the email.
'   Attachments     A single file name or an array of file names to
'                   attach to the message. The files must exist.
' Return Value:
'   True if successful.
'   False if failure.
'
' Subject may not be an empty string.
' FromAddress must be a valid email address.
' ToAddress must be a valid email address. To send to multiple recipients,
' use a semi-colon to separate the individual addresses. If there is a
' failure in one address, processing terminates and messages are not
' send to the rest of the recipients.
' If MailBody is vbNullString and BodyFileName is an existing text file, the content
' of the file named by BodyFileName is put into the body of the email. If
' BodyFileName does not exist, the function returns False. The content of
' the message body is created by a line-by-line import from BodyFileName.
' If MailBody is not vbNullString, then BodyFileName is ignored and the body
' is not created from the file.
' SMTP_Server must be a valid accessable SMTP server name.
' If both MailBody and BodyFileName are vbNullString, the mail message is
' sent with no body content.
' Attachments can be either a single file name as a String or an array of
' file names. If an attachment file does not exist, it is skipped but
' does not cause the procedure to terminate.
'
' If you want to send ThisWorkbook as an attachment to the message, use code
' like the following:
'    ThisWorkbook.Save
'    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
'    B = SendEmail( _
'        ... parameters ...
'        Attachments:=ThisWorkbook.FullName)
'    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadWrite
'
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Required References:
' --------------------
'   Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library
'       Typical File Location: C:\Windows\system32\cdosys.dll
'       GUID: {CD000000-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D}
'       Major: 1    Minor: 0
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim MailMessage As CDO.Message
Dim N As Long
Dim FNum As Integer
Dim S As String
Dim Body As String
Dim Recips() As String
Dim Recip As String
Dim NRecip As Long

' ensure required parameters are present and valid.
If Len(Trim(Subject)) = 0 Then
    SendEMail = False
    Exit Function
End If

If Len(Trim(FromAddress)) = 0 Then
    SendEMail = False
    Exit Function
End If

If Len(Trim(SMTP_Server)) = 0 Then
    SendEMail = False
    Exit Function
End If

' Clean up the addresses
Recip = Replace(ToAddress, Space(1), vbNullString)
If Right(Recip, 1) = ";" Then
    Recip = Left(Recip, Len(Recip) - 1)
End If
Recips = Split(Recip, ";")


For NRecip = LBound(Recips) To UBound(Recips)
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Create a CDO Message object.
    Set MailMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        SendEMail = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    With MailMessage
        .Subject = Subject
        .From = FromAddress
        .To = Recips(NRecip)
        If MailBody <> vbNullString Then
            .TextBody = MailBody
        Else
            If BodyFileName <> vbNullString Then
                If Dir(BodyFileName, vbNormal) <> vbNullString Then
                    ' import the text of the body from file BodyFileName
                    FNum = FreeFile
                    S = vbNullString
                    Body = vbNullString
                    Open BodyFileName For Input Access Read As #FNum
                    Do Until EOF(FNum)
                        Line Input #FNum, S
                        Body = Body & vbNewLine & S
                    Loop
                    Close #FNum
                    .TextBody = Body
                Else
                    ' BodyFileName not found.
                    SendEMail = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If ' MailBody and BodyFileName are both vbNullString.
        End If

        If IsArray(Attachments) = True Then
            ' attach all the files in the array.
            For N = LBound(Attachments) To UBound(Attachments)
                ' ensure the attachment file exists and attach it.
                If Attachments(N) <> vbNullString Then
                    If Dir(Attachments(N), vbNormal) <> vbNullString Then
                        .AddAttachment Attachments(N)
                    End If
                End If
            Next N
        Else
            ' ensure the file exists and if so, attach it to the message.
            If Attachments <> vbNullString Then
                If Dir(CStr(Attachments), vbNormal) <> vbNullString Then
                    .AddAttachment Attachments
                End If
            End If
        End If
        With .Configuration.Fields
            ' set up the SMTP configuration
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTP_Server
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
            .Update
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        ' Send the message
        .Send
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            SendEMail = True
        Else
            SendEMail = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
Next NRecip
SendEMail = True
End Function
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. My users will not know there smtp details and I dont want to phone/explain to all of them how to get it. On second thought i could send them a pdf or word doc explaining how to get the smtp details, but I think that will be too hard for them!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use MAPI?

This is from the MS Knowledge Base:

```
   Dim objSession As Object
   Dim objMessage As Object
   Dim objRecipient As Object

   'Create the Session Object.
   Set objSession = CreateObject("mapi.session")

   'Logon using the session object.
   'Specify a valid profile name if you want to.
   'Avoid the logon dialog box.
   objSession.Logon profileName:="MS Exchange Settings"

   'Add a new message object to the OutBox.
   Set objMessage = objSession.Outbox.Messages.Add

   'Set the properties of the message object.
   objMessage.subject = "This is a test."
   objMessage.Text = "This is the message text."

   'Add a recipient object to the objMessage.Recipients collection.
   Set objRecipient = objMessage.Recipients.Add

   'Set the properties of the recipient object.
   objRecipient.Name = "John Doe"  '<---Replace this with a valid
                                   'display name or e-mail alias
   'Type can be ActMsgTo, mapiTo, or CdoTo for different CDO versions;
   'they all have a constant value of 1.
   objRecipient.Type = mapiTo
   objRecipient.Resolve

   'Send the message.
   objMessage.Send showDialog:=False
   MsgBox "Message sent successfully!"

   'Logoff using the session object.
   objSession.Logoff
```

Comment: Thx. I'll test this. Will everyone go through an Exchange mail server if they are using outlook ? And will the above method show any security popups? Sorry if i'm asking silly questions.